# weird python nameError

Tags: python, tkinter, global

When I try to run my code I get an error saying that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vilho/PycharmProjects/BitlifeYritys1.0/main.py", line 37, in <module>
    kill = Button(screen1, text="End game", bg="green", command=end_game("end game button was pressed"), height=4, width=11)
  File "C:/Users/Vilho/PycharmProjects/BitlifeYritys1.0/main.py", line 9, in end_game
    main_screen.destroy()
NameError: name 'main_screen' is not defined
```

I don't know what caused the error because I tried to put globals everywhere I could.
The rest of the code is here:
https://shrib.com/?v=nc#VioletCrestedTuraco4wYoed9

Comment: This will give you a different error: None type object does not have the method destroy

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site. Instead, [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You don't define main_screen until you call main_game:

```
def main_game():
    global main_screen
    main_screen = Tk()
```

But you never call this function.

You do, however, call the end_game function. This means that you are calling the destroy method on an object that does not yet exist:

```
main_screen.destroy()
```

Conclusion: you either need make sure that main_game is called before end_game, or you need to create a blank window (which might not be the best idea).